# HTTP Post on Ionic 3 giving 400 error; can't send the body parameter

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to call post method on the API (http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/) which requires only a single body parameter (key: "text") for it to respond correctly. It works flawlessly on Postman. I have used these methods to get the post response successfully in the past, but those APIs required body parameter in raw format. I have tried every methods for passing the body parameter, both in raw and JSON format, but it always give the 400 error.

```
this.textHeaders = new Headers();
this.textHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/form-data");

let bodyParam = new FormData();

    bodyParam.append('text', 'I like it');
// bodyParam.append('I like it', 'text'); // This doesn't work either

this.textOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.textHeaders});

this.http.post("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/", bodyParam, this.textOptions)
.map(res=>res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
      this.textOutput = data;
      console.log(this.textOutput);
   }, error => {
      console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
      console.error('API Error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
});

let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', bodyParam, this.textOptions)
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) =>
    {
        console.log('API Response : ', response.json());
        resolve(response.json());
    })
        .catch((error) =>
    {
        console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
        console.error('API Error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
        reject(error.json());
    });
});
```

[API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gwt3.png)

[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCroa.png)

Edit: [Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05UrN.png), [Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O73d2.png), [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaHG3.png)

Edit: Following libraries are used

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

Tried changing "Content-Type" to "application/json" and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but same results.

Comment: You should post the content of the Headers pane in Network tab of the Chrome dev tools, so that we can check the complete query.

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the complete request as seen in the Network tab of Chrome Dev tools ?

Comment: Added. Check the edit.

Comment: What library are you using for http ?

Comment: Default core libraries.

    import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

Comment: Danyal did you try sending a plain JSON object with an application/json content-type ?

Comment: Didn't work. Same error '400'. Do you want request headers/response images of this call?

Comment: In the same file, if I add a post call to a different API that requires body parameter in JSON/raw format then the response is successful (if you want the code, I can give you that). The error clearly indicates the problem is in client code not sending the data properly. The same error is received on Postman when the "text" field isn't given. As you have asked me to send plain JSON object, I have tried doing so in Postman as well, didn't work. It works only in "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlecnoded" format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a 400 or a 405? If a 400, you want to change your URL to https.

Comment: That doesn't ring true with the validation messages he's getting though (see the image lings) unless Ionic silently strips posted bodies over HTTP. And it looks like it's working fine over HTTP with Postman.

Comment: Tried using https. Didn't work. It is giving error code '0'.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - no help. I've set it up and tried several things and cannot get past the Bad Request.

Comment: On a side note, 'ionic serve' gives error code '0' as well. Had to test on the device to get past that error. It has to do with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" thing that browsers have trouble with.

Comment: @SteveKenney Any luck so far? I have attached the images of request headers in original post.

Comment: @DanyalZia nothing but the Bad Request. If you want to get past the Access Control issue (CORS) locally, for future needs, you can set up a proxy server - that ends up being an edit of ionic.config.json.

Comment: @SteveKenney Thanks. Would you mind elaborating the method to set proxy server or give me some external link/guide for editing ionic.config.json? Simply changing "proxyUrl" to the API address didn't work.

Comment: Sure. Basically when developing locally, many APIs will reject your http request due to CORS. Ionic makes it easy to get past this (locally only) by configuring the ionic.config.json. You can see a good example here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html (search for 'Service Proxies'). Then your actual post needs to call your local server, adding only the part of the path that would be after the domain. So for the text-processing site, your http post would be to http://localhost:8100/api/sentiment/ - then the proxy settings redirect to the real site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the multipart is an issue here. Didn't test this but you can try sending a plain json object :

```
this.textHeaders = new Headers();
this.textHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

let data = {'text': 'I like it' };

this.textOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.textHeaders});

this.http.post("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/", data, this.textOptions)
.map(res=>res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
      this.textOutput = data;
      console.log(this.textOutput);
   }, error => {
      console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
      console.error('API Error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
});

let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', bodyParam, this.textOptions)
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) =>
    {
        console.log('API Response : ', response.json());
        resolve(response.json());
    })
        .catch((error) =>
    {
        console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
        console.error('API Error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
        reject(error.json());
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have a working code that calls an external API and passes the body parameter in form-data? That could help.